# Differently named appendices and appendix style in TOC

Tags: appendices

I have 2 problems.

The first problem is that we should have two different appendices, with two different names, one named Appendikser and one named Bilag. It should be as two different chapters, and the section should also reset back from Appendix C to Appendix A.

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendikser}
\addto\captionsdanish{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Appendisker}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendikser}
}

%Appendix
\begin{appendices}
\input{Appendix/LIAL.tex}
\pagebreak
\input{Appendix/Cobb.tex}
\end{appendices}

%Bilag
\begin{appendices}
\input{Bilag/KKTEksempel.tex}
\pagebreak
\input{Bilag/CaseKKT.tex}
```

with this code, both titles are called "Appendikser" and it just continues the section counter.

The second problem is figuring out how to indent "Appendix A" in the Table of Contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to the first part of the problem

```
%Appendix
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

%Change name in TOC
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendikser}

%Change Appendix in the language package to be danish
\addto\captionsdanish{%
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Appendikser}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendikser}
} 

%Bilag
\newenvironment{Bilag}[1]{
%Reset Appenix counter
\makeatletter
\setcounter{@ppsaveapp}{0}
\makeatother
%Choose name of the new environment and adding it
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Bilag}
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Bilag}
  \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Bilag}
\begin{appendices}#1}
{\end{appendices}}
```